# getting list items as json instead of xml/atom

Tags: angular, sharepoint

When I type the link of list in browser I am able to see all data in xml/atom format, screenshot below
[image]

I searched and to make this incoming response as JSON I used "RequestOptionsArgs"(I am using Typescript&Angular2) object but this time there is no content of list but telling me msg "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException". it says invalid authentication.. But only tried to change response data format, I already can see data inside of xml content. here my service and consuming method;

```
import {Http,RequestOptionsArgs,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable}  from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ListService {
    constructor(private http_: Http){}

    getAnnouncements(urllapi){
        urllapi = "http://urll/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Announcement5Jan')/items";
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        let opts:RequestOptionsArgs = { headers: headers };
        return this.http_.get(urllapi/*, opts */).map(res=>res.json());
        //getting data as xml with this. if I comment out opts parameter no data but sp.exception
    }
}
```

its called;

```
this.spotfyService.getAnnouncements("").subscribe((res) => {
             debugger
             console.log("data:"+res)});
```

How can I retrieve these items rigth?

Comment: you want as xml or json?

Comment: hi, its xml already, I need it as json

Comment: to which object are you mapping where is the mapping code?

Comment: mapping code? what do you mean mapping code ? I already used in "return this.http_.get(urllapi/*, opts */).map(res=>res.json());" line do you mean there is some other stuff needed to handle this?

Comment: do you mind I need to create a model(interface) of these item ?

Comment: Yes I want to know if you have created an interface?

Comment: no man I didnt such a thing, but even I didnt,  Its supposed to be retrieve data rigth? Do you advice create interface, use xml to model mapping instead of using json ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133252/discussion-between-tyforhelpdude-and-aravind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because header parameters added to rest api. To do this rigth way I have used spfx HttpClient api, here is my working code sample:

```
  export default class Announcements extends React.Component<IAnnouncementProperties, IWebPartState> {

      private listItemEntityTypeName: string = "SP.Data.AnnouncementsListItem";//Announcement2ListItem
      private siteUrl: string = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/site26jan";
...

private readItems(skip, take): void {
    this.props.httpClient.get(`${this.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items?&$top=${take}`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: Response): Promise<{ value: IAnnouncement[] }> => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response: { value: IAnnouncement[] }): void => {
        this.setState({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${response.value.length} items`,
          items: response.value
        });
      }, (error: any): void => {
        this.setState({
          status: 'Loading all items failed with error: ' + error,
          items: []
        });
      });
  }
```

Now it gets data as json from SP as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is only half true - this is how things are supposed to work, but some sharepoint queries ignore the settings, and even if you define the headers and pass them to the get function it gets ignored and you get XML.
For example, the method above works for the query in the example, but if you change the url to

this.props.httpClient.get(`${this.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/?$select=ID`

you get XML regardless of the request. I got the same problem when doing queries on list items without a "select" clause but with a filter on a certain field - adding the select clause solved it.
I am still looking into why this is happening and how to work around it.